# How to send a S3 bucket notification on SNS with a presigned url to new object uploaded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

I would like to configure a bucket notification on an S3 bucket so that every time a notification from a file being uploaded, it sends a message to an SNS topic with a pre signed url in the message so that file can be downloaded when consumed from an email.

File gets uploaded -> notification sent to SNS containing presigned url to recently updated object -> to SNS topic -> to email -> to user

I have tried setting up a topic, but couldn't get a presigned url inside the message, is there a way of setting this up without using a lambda or queue or other AWS services as intermediates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without additional services.

S3 is a storage service, as such it doesn't to much computation if any.

The simplest way would be to create a Lambda that gets triggered on S3 put object, generates the presigned url and sends a message to an SQS or SNS topic.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a Lambda for this unfortunately, it shouldn't be too much additional work.